# How to fix ORA-01427

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm working on converting a stored procedure from SQL to Oracle and I get this error:

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "CMIUSER.PROCEDURE3", line 21
ORA-06512: at line 7

t_name_match and t_descript_match are global temp tables.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "PROCEDURE3" 
(
  IN_SEARCH_TEXT IN NVARCHAR2 
, OUT_O_RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS  
BEGIN
/*******************************************************************************    ***
** Name matches
********************************************************************************    ***/
/*
** Load matches to Name Table
*/
INSERT INTO t_name_match (KBID, SYMBOLID, FEATURENAME)
SELECT  fm.KBID, fm.SYMBOLID, fm.FEATURENAME
  from  FEATURE_MASTER fm
 where  Upper(featurename) like IN_SEARCH_TEXT;
/*
** Add description for each of these matching names.
*/

UPDATE  t_name_match nm
SET nm.DESCRIPT = (SELECT x.DESCRIPT
  from  CHAR_FEATURE_XRF    x
  where x.KBID = nm.KBID
    and x.SYMBOLID = nm.SYMBOLID);

/*******************************************************************************    ***
** Description matches
********************************************************************************    ***/
/*
** Load matches to Descript table
*/
INSERT INTO t_descript_match (KBID, SYMBOLID, DESCRIPT)
SELECT  x.KBID, x.SYMBOLID, x.DESCRIPT
  from  CHAR_FEATURE_XRF x
 where  Upper(descript) like IN_SEARCH_TEXT;


/*
** Add name for each of these matching descriptions.
*/

UPDATE  t_descript_match dm
SET dm.FEATURENAME = (SELECT f.FEATURENAME
  from  FEATURE_MASTER      f
  where f.KBID = dm.KBID
    and f.SYMBOLID = dm.SYMBOLID);

/*******************************************************************************    ***
** Return result set
********************************************************************************    ***/
 OPEN OUT_O_RC FOR
SELECT nm.featurename, nm.descript
  from  t_name_match nm
  UNION
 SELECT dm.featurename, dm.descript
  from  t_descript_match dm
ORDER BY featurename, descript;



END PROCEDURE3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place (that I notice) where you have a "single row subquery" is:

```
UPDATE  t_name_match nm
    SET nm.DESCRIPT = (SELECT x.DESCRIPT
                       from  CHAR_FEATURE_XRF x
                       where x.KBID = nm.KBID and x.SYMBOLID = nm.SYMBOLID
                      );
```

How you fix it depends on what you want to do.  Two simple ways are `MAX()` and `rownum = 1`:

```
UPDATE  t_name_match nm
    SET nm.DESCRIPT = (SELECT MAX(x.DESCRIPT)
                       from  CHAR_FEATURE_XRF x
                       where x.KBID = nm.KBID and x.SYMBOLID = nm.SYMBOLID
                      );

UPDATE  t_name_match nm
    SET nm.DESCRIPT = (SELECT x.DESCRIPT
                       from  CHAR_FEATURE_XRF x
                       where x.KBID = nm.KBID and x.SYMBOLID = nm.SYMBOLID and
                             rownum = 1
                      );
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see there are two places.  The other is:

```
UPDATE t_descript_match dm
    SET dm.FEATURENAME = (SELECT f.FEATURENAME
                          from  FEATURE_MASTER f
                          where f.KBID = dm.KBID and f.SYMBOLID = dm.SYMBOLID
                         );
```

You would fix it the same way.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue and I'm getting the right results back.

Answer (score 1):

```
    UPDATE  t_name_match nm
    SET nm.DESCRIPT = (SELECT x.DESCRIPT
    from  CHAR_FEATURE_XRF    x
    where x.KBID = nm.KBID
    and x.SYMBOLID = nm.SYMBOLID group by x.DESCRIPT);


    UPDATE  t_descript_match dm
    SET dm.FEATURENAME = (SELECT f.FEATURENAME
    from  FEATURE_MASTER      f
    where f.KBID = dm.KBID
    and f.SYMBOLID = dm.SYMBOLID group by f.FEATURENAME);
```

can you try these and check.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.  This method does work, but I chose Gordon's method as I think it's more aligned with what I needed.

Comment: This method only works if the duplicate rows have the same values.  If there are multiple values, then this will generate an error.  As a general rule:  don't use `group by` in scalar subqueries (subqueries that can only return one row).

Comment: Correct, for multiple values this will generate an error. But since nothing was mentioned about the requirement I presumed that identical rows might be causing the problem.